# How to set fontsize for XSSF-Header of Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Recently, I need to export an excel with Java.  So I chose the Apache POI, by experience.

But today, someone told me that the header of excel needs to be modified to 18-size font. I look for relevant api in Header and Sheet, but found nothing helpful.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The header I mentioned is sheet.getHeader(),  not the first row of the sheet.   Thanks anyway.

Comment: Check [**this**](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Header) link.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found this way just now, too ~~  ^_^